# When inheriting buttons from a parent form in the child, the buttons do not retain the same position

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My problem is exactly that the inheritance of the forms, when opening, closing or compiling the child form the buttons behave as if they had a life of their own, they move from place

Here I attach a link to see what happens to me, I know that putting links is a bad practice, but I need to explain my problem as best as possible

https://1drv.ms/v/s!ApYO6DZzi_l-8zp-Fvr4nFkgta5J?e=d482SE

These are the information for a minimum and reproducible example, I use DevExpress, hopefully it is not a problem

**Inherit Parent Form**

```
 public partial class BaseMantenimiento1 : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        public BaseMantenimiento1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

private void Nuevo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Guardar.Enabled = true;
    Cancelar.Enabled = true;
    Editar.Enabled = false;
    Buscar.Enabled = false;
    Nuevo.Enabled = false;
}

public void Guardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Nuevo.Enabled = true;
    Guardar.Enabled = false;
    Cancelar.Enabled = false;
    Buscar.Enabled = true;
    Editar.Enabled = true;
}

private void Cancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Guardar.Enabled = false;
    Cancelar.Enabled = false;
    Nuevo.Enabled = true;
    Editar.Enabled = true;
    Buscar.Enabled = true;
}

private void Editar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Nuevo.Enabled = false;
    Buscar.Enabled = false;
    Editar.Enabled = false;
    Guardar.Enabled = true;
    Cancelar.Enabled = true;
}
 }
}
```

**Inherit Child Form**

```
public partial class Form1 : BaseMantenimiento1
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What is that link to? That seems pretty sketch to force us to somehow login to take a look at it. Use a different method to share that information with us...

Comment: @Idle_Mind With all due respect, apparently you didn't try to open the link, the link contains a video that describes exactly what my problem is as describing it in words is hard, so next time hit the link and confirm if it asks for any kind. login as this is direct from my personal OneDrive

Comment: @Yisus if you "know that putting links is bad practice" then why do you persist in doing it?

Comment: @IVSoftware As I said in my post, describing exactly my problem is difficult, it's like the buttons have a life of their own, if you watch the video that contains the link you can see what I mean, really what I need is help with my problem, I try to look for a solution and the most explicit way to explain it

Comment: Um, no. I did click on the link and it wanted me to sign up or sign in, so I did neither. It's not a direct link to a video as you claim. Perhaps it's "direct" for you as you're logged in to that service.

Answer (score 0):

My guess (I cannot access your link to see what the actual problem is) is that the assignment of the event handlers is only happening in the parent form's `InitializeComponent`, not the child form. Since it is generated by the designer you could either wire them up in the designer for the child form or in the constructor of the child form after `InitializeComponent` is called.

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry I forgot to copy the part of the InitializeComponent for the post in the photo, but I checked these parts and I have the same problem, try to access the link again so you can see what my specific problem is, my inheritance works fine, but the buttons move as if they had a life of their own